# A result from Peter McMullen's thesis

Tags: co.combinatorics, discrete-geometry, reflection-groups

The classical definition of regular polytopes is recursive. It says that a polytope is regular if its facets and vertex figures (both smaller-dimensional polytopes) are regular.

The modern definition goes as follows. Let $P\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ be a polytope centered at the origin and let $\mathrm{Aut}(P)\leq O(n)$ be its automorphism group. We say that $P$ is regular if its automorphism group acts transitively on maximal flags of faces.

However, there are many equivalent definitions of regularity. Let's say that a polytope is $d$-regular if its automorphism group is transitive on $d$-dimensional faces. The following theorem is stated in several places (for example in McMullen and Schulte's "Abstract Regular Polytopes", pages 9-10):

Theorem: Let $P$ be an $n$-dimensional polytope. If $P$ is $d$-regular for all $0\leq d\leq n-1$ then $P$ is regular.

All statements of this theorem I've seen refer to Peter McMullen's 1968 thesis from the University of Birmingham, which I don't have access to.

So here's my question: Does anyone know where I can find a proof of this theorem or how to gain access to Peter McMullen's thesis?

Bonus Problem: How dependent/independent are the notions of $d$-regularity for different $d$?

Thanks.

Comment: This seems to need a clarification on automorphisms: clearly the cyclic group of order $n$ acting naturally on the regular $n$-gon is transitive on its vertices and edges, but not on flags. So the statement seems to boil down to a finite Coxeter group in the background...

Comment: "How dependent/independent are the notions of $d$-regularity for different $d$": I have looked into this specific question for almost two years now, and it seems that surprisingly little is known (there is even a quote in Grünbaum's "Convex Polytopes" hinting to that lack of knowledge). See e.g. [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/338332/108884) of mine, for which the answer is *No* (at least that is what my results tell me; it is still unpublished).

Answer (score 8):

This is theorem 4C6 of Peter McMullen's thesis, "On the Combinatorial Structure of Convex Polytopes", on page 73:

> 4C6. Theorem. A $d$-polytope $P$ is regular if and only if for each $j = 0, \dots, d-1$, its symmetry group $G(P)$ is transitive on the $j$-faces of $P$.
>
> The condition is clearly necessary. For the converse, we deduce that
>   the vertices of $P$ lie on a $(d-1)$-sphere, $S^{d-1}$, and hence that
>   the vertices of any $j$-face $F^j$ $(j=1,\dots,d)$ lie on the
>   $(j-1)$-sphere $S^{d-1} \cap \operatorname{aff} F^j$. If we assume
>   inductively that the facets of $F^j$ are regular and congruent, then
>   by theorem 4C4, we deduce that $F^j$ is itself regular. In particular,
>   for $j = d$, we deduce that $P$ is regular. This completes the proof
>   of theorem 4C6.

Theorem 4C4 says

> 4C4. Theorem. A $d$-polytope $P$ ($d \geq 3$) is regular if and only
>   if its vertices lie on a sphere, and its facets are regular and
>   combinatorially equivalent.
>
> That the condition is necessary is clear, since the transforms of a
>   point under a finite group of congruent transformations lie on a
>   sphere. We prove that the condition is sufficient by induction on the
>   dimension $d$. Since two adjacent facets share a $(d-2)$-face, using
>   proposition 1C16 we deduce that any two facets of $P$ are congruent.
>   In particular, the edges of $P$ have the same length. This implies
>   that the mid-points of the edges of $P$ through any given vertex lie
>   on a $(d-2)$-sphere. But these points are the vertices of a
>   vertex-figure of $P$ (cf. proposition 1B4); its facets are congruent,
>   and so by the induction hypothesis, it is regular. (Notice that this
>   holds for the case $d=2$ as well.) In 3 dimensions, this condition
>   also implies that the vertex-figures, being regular polygons with the
>   same edge-length inscribed in circles of the same radius, are
>   congruent. Hence, by theorems 4C2 and 4C3, $P$ is regular, which
>   completes the proof of theorem 4C4.

The mentioned results are

- 1C16: Any two $j$-faces $F^j$ and $G^j$ of a polytope $P$ can be joined by a chain
  $$F^j = F_0^j, F_1^j, \dots, F_m^j = G^j$$
  of $j$-faces of $P$, such that for $k = 1, \dots, m$, $F_{k-1}^j$ and $F_k^j$ are adjacent.
- 1B4: $H \cap P \approx P / F$, where $F$ is a vertex of a polytope $P$, and $H$ is a hyperplane strictly separating $F$ from the remaining vertices $P \setminus F$ of $P$.
- 4C2: A $d$-polytope $P$ ($d \geq 3$) is regular if and only if its facets are regular and combinatorially equivalent, and its vertex-figures are combinatorially regular and combinatorially equivalent.
- 4C3: A $d$-polytope $P$ ($d \geq 4$) is regular if and only if its facets are regular and its vertex-figures are combinatorially regular.

Answer (score 5):

As far as I can tell, this was published:

MR0221384 (36 #4436) Reviewed 
McMullen, P.
Combinatorially regular polytopes. 
Mathematika 14 1967 142–150.

Comment: This seems not to contain the result I'm looking for. Probably it's implicit, but too implicit for me.