# Is there any edge- but not vertex-transitive polytope in $d\ge 4$ dimensions?

Tags: co.combinatorics, mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry, convex-polytopes, polytopes

I consider convex polytopes $P\subset\Bbb R^d$. The polytope is called *vertex*- resp. *edge-transitive*, if any vertex resp. edge can be mapped to any other by a symmetry of the polytope.

I am looking for polytopes which are edge- but *not* vertex-transitive. There are infinitely many of these for $d=2$, and exactly two for $d=3$ (rhombic dodecahedron and rhombic tricontrahedron, see below).

$\quad$$\quad$ [image]$\quad$$\quad$
[image]

I do not know a single example for $d\ge 4$.

I believe it is easy to see that the edge-graph of such a polytope must be bipartite, and thus, zonotopes might be a good place to start looking. But my constructions fail for $d\ge 4$.

Comment: To echo your bipartite point: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge-transitive_graph) says "Every edge-transitive graph that is not vertex-transitive must be bipartite and either semi-symmetric or biregular."

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke That was my thought. But one has to be careful: the symmetry group of the polytope might be smaller than the one of its edge-graph. "Bipartite" should still hold, but I do not immediately know about "semi-symmetric or biregular". Update: I have read the definition of these terms, and they should *probably* still hold.

Comment: Both your examples in d=3 are the convex hull of the union of a regular polyhedron and its dual (appropriately scaled). Have you tried this construction in d=4?

Comment: @YoavKallus That's a great idea. Thank you. What else comes to my mind now is to let a vertex grow out of each facet of a (regular) polytope and at some point the original edges will vanish in the inside of a facet. This might give examples. This corresponds to your idea of looking for the "appropriate scaling". And no, have not tried this, but will do so now.

Comment: @YoavKallus At least the construction using the 4-cube and the 4-crosspolytope does not work (no matter the scaling, their are at least two orbits of edges).

Comment: @M.Winter Actually, there is a scaling where you get only one orbit of edges, but the problem is you also get only one orbit of vertices (the 24 cell). The scaling that makes the cross-polytope 2-faces co-3-planar with the cube edges does seem to have two edge orbits but one 2-face orbit. So it is in some way a generalization of the constructions above, but not in the desired way.

Comment: @YoavKallus I also had the idea that this should give the 24-cell, but somehow I wasn't able to find the correct scaling for that. To give a vertex transitive polytope, the hypercube must have vertices $(\pm1,\pm1,\pm1,\pm1)$ and the 16-cell must have permutations of $(\pm2,0,0,0)$. But under a (now deleted) answer, we came to the conclusion that this polytope has extra edges orbits. Or am I mistaking somewhere. To the second part of your comment: if you have a 2-face transitive 4-polytope, then the dual of that is edge-transitive, isn't it? Could this be an example?

Comment: @M.Winter I thought so too at first, but if I did my calculaions correctly, the 3-faces seem to also be in a single orbit, so the dual would be vertex-transitive and would not be an example.

Comment: The scaling with vertex set permutations of $(\pm 2,0,0,0)$ and $(\pm 1,\pm 1,\pm 1,\pm 1)$ is the 24-cell and it is completely regular (i.e., the group of symmetries is flag transitive).  Each vertex has 8 nearest neighbours.  The dual is another copy of the 24-cell, with vertex set the permutations of $(\pm 1, \pm 1, 0, 0)$.  You might try to same construction for $d>4$; in that case there are definitely two orbits of vertices.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer is *No*, there are no other such polytopes. The proof is quite laborious in parts, and I wrote it down in [this article](https://arxiv.org/abs/2005.14285).

> **Theorem.** In dimension $d\ge 4$, an edge-transitive polytope is vertex-transitive.

The idea is as follows: first, show that every edge-transitive polytope $P$ that is not vertex-transitive has the following three properties:

1. all edges of $P$ are of the same length,
2. $P$ has an edge in-sphere, and
3. the edge-graph of $P$ is bipartite.

Call a polytope with these three properties **bipartite**.
One then tries to classify these polytopes instead.
This is easier, because every face of a bipartite polytope is again bipartite (not true for edge- or vertex-transitive polytopes).

The second step is to deal with all *inscribed* bipartite polytopes.
It is not hard to see that these are zonotopes. By a result from [this article](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00454-021-00303-6) (see also [this](https://mathoverflow.net/q/342367/108884) question), inscribed zonotopes with all edges of the same length are vertex-transitive. We can therefore exclude all the inscribed bipartite polytopes.

In the third step one classifies all the *3-dimensional non-inscribed* bipartite *polyhedra*.
This is quite tedious.
Here is one example of a polyhedron which satisfies 2. and 3., but fails to have all edges of the same length.
The deviation is so miniscule, that it cannot be spotted visually.

[image]

The result is then that there are only two such polyhedra: exactly those that I already mentioned in the question.

The final step is then to show that no 4-dimensional non-inscribed bipartite polytope can be built if we can use only these two polyhedra as facets. This uses a straight-forward argument on dihedral angles (see also [Nick's answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/345272/108884)).

Answer (score 4):

If you consider a tiling of 3-space to be a 4-dimensional polytope, then the [Rhombic dodecahedral honeycomb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhombic_dodecahedral_honeycomb) would work.

Other possibilities are limited by the potential 3-faces. 
Because every edge has one endpoint in each of two vertex orbits,
the 2-faces must all have evenly many sides.

If the edge-transitivity descends to the 3-faces, then the 3-faces must be among the [9 isotoxal polyhedra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_isotoxal_polyhedra_and_tilings#Convex_isotoxal_polyhedra): the five Platonic solids, the cuboctahedron, the icosidodecahedron, the rhombic dodecahedron, or the rhombic triacontahedron. 
The only ones of these with only even-length faces are the 3-cube, the rhombic dodecahedron, and the rhombic triacontahedron.
With dihedral angles of 90°, 120°, and 144° respectively, these can only build up the 4-cube, the cubic tiling of 3-space, and the above-mentioned rhombic dodecahedral honeycomb.
(A subgroup of the 4-cube's symmetry group acts in an edge-transitive but not vertex-transitive manner; you can color alternate vertices in two colors).

On the other hand, perhaps the 3-faces are not isotoxal: this occurs if, for some pair of edges $e$ and $e'$ of a 3-face $G$, every symmetry mapping $e$ to $e'$ also maps $G$ to
a different 3-face incident to $e'$. In this case we can still say that the 3-cells are equilateral polyhedra
with all even-length faces. There's also fairly strong requirements on the vertex figures, which must be vertex-transitive.

Answer (score -1):

You can 1-subdivide any regular polytope to obtain edge-transitive but not vertex-transitive bipartite graph. More generally, you can take an incidence graph between k-faces and r-faces in a regular polytope. By incidence I mean putting an edge if one contains the other.

If you don't want a geometric property, e.g., convexity, then you can easily do so by taking any favourite finite group of yours. Namely, take a group G, take two subgroups H1 and H2 that have different indices, and consider the incidence graph with cosets, i.e., gH1 and gH2 are adjacent. The group G acts transitively on each side and on edges, but one cannot map a vertex to the other side.

The face-incidence example is indeed a special case of this algebraic construction, by taking two parabolic subgroups that correspond to faces.

Comment: Sorry, but I do not understand how any of these gives a *convex* edge-transitive polytope. E.g. the first part: I cannot just subdivide the edges of a regular polytope, I have to change the geometry for that too, and by that, probably create other edges.