# Classification of vertex-transitive zonotopes

Tags: co.combinatorics, discrete-geometry, convex-polytopes, polytopes, zonotopes

[Zonotopes](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Zonotope.html) are convex polytopes that can be defined in several equivalent ways:

- parallel projections of cubes,
- Minkowsi sums of line segments,
- only centrally symmetric faces,
- ...

I wonder whether there exists a calssification of all **vertex-transitive** zonotopes. I know only of the following examples:

- [omnitruncations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omnitruncation) of uniform polytopes (this is probably the same as $W$-permutahedra, see comments). This already includes the interval $[0,1]$, all regular $2n$-gons, and, e.g. the following polyhedra in $\smash{\Bbb R^3}$:

$\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad$[image]
[image]
[image]

- cartesian products of any of these above. This includes $d$-cubes, prisms, duo-prisms, ...

Are there any more? For that matter, are there even any more zonotopes for which all vertices are on a common sphere?

Comment: How about permutohedra (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutohedron) and more generally $W$-permutohedra (old name: Coxeterhedra) for Weyl groups $W$?

Comment: @SamHopkins I suspect that these are exactly the omnitruncations.

Comment: I'm not so sure about these "omnitruncations": do you get one for each crystallographic root system? The diagrams on that wiki page seem a bit different.

Comment: @Sam If I have a reflection group, then I can define the omnitruncated uniform polytope to that group. Is that what you meant? I am not sure about the (now deleted) modified weight part.

Comment: (The modified weight part was wrong- those deformed permutohedra are not actually zonotopes.)

Comment: I am not an expert about uniform polytopes, but I was lead to believe that there is no uniform polytope e.g. corresponding to the root system $E_8$ (because the $E_8$ Dynkin diagram has a trivalent node); however, there is an $E_8$-permutohedron.

Comment: @SamHopkins There is indeed one ;) see [E8 polytopes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E8_polytope). The omnitruncated one is not listed there, but one can write down its Coxeter diagram (all nodes ringed), so it exists. Maybe a point of confusion was that initially my questions stated "regular polytopes" instead of "uniform polytopes", which was indeed too restrictive. I changed that.

Comment: Basic observations: Let $Z$ be the zonotope and let $G$ be its symmetry group. We can assume that the center of mass of $Z$ is at $0$ and, by the standard averaging argument, we can assume that $G$ acts by orthogonal matrices. The normal fan to $Z$ is a hyperplane arrangement $\bigcup H_i$. We would like to know that $G$ contains the reflections over the hyperplanes $H_i$, because then $Z$ would be a $W$-permutahedron for the corresponding reflection group $W$.

Comment: One frustrating thing is that $G$ can be larger than $W$. For example, the symmetry group of the square is dihedral of order $8$, but the reflections over the two $H_i$ only generate a subgroup of order $4$.

Comment: @DavidESpeyer I also think it is the right thing to conjecture that they all are $W$-permutahedra. I was thinking about the line segments that generate the zonotope and came to the conclusion that these form a root system, but without the integrality condition (what is this called?). The details are messy though, and I am not ready to write this up.

Comment: Personally, I'd still call them roots, but no one will argue with your terminology if you say that the dual hyperplanes come from a finite reflection group.

Comment: What about the truncated 24-cell and the omnitruncated grand antiprism (not a W-permutahedra)?

Comment: @Bullet51 I think you are right. Could you clear up something in the Wikipedia article? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_24-cells says that the truncated 24-cell is the Minkowski sum of line segments joining the twelve permutations of $(1,-1,0,0)$. But those $12$ points lie in the plane $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4= 0$, so that Minkowski sum should be 3-dimensional, not 4-dimensional. Do you know what is going on?

Comment: Wikipedia also says that this is the convex hull of all permutations and sign changes of $(0,1,2,3)$. But this can also be described as the $D_4$ orbit of $(0,1,2,3)$, and $(0,1,2,3)$ has no stabilizer for the $D_4$ action. So is this just the $D_4$-permutahedron?

Comment: I am also reading the Wikipedia article on the Grand Antiprism. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grand_antiprism . I see that the Grand Antiprism has tetrahedral faces. Am I guessing correctly that the omnitruncated grand antiprism has faces that are truncated (or possibly rectified) tetrahedra? Because truncated/rectified tetrahedra are not zonotopes, and that would mean that the omnitruncated grand antiprism wouldn't be either.

Comment: @Bullet51 Both of these are no counterexamples: 1. the truncated 24-cell is identical to the omnitruncated [demitesseract](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demihypercube) (as written on the Wikipedia page of the truncated 24-cell). As David said, it is the $D_4$-permutahedron. 2. omnitruncations are (as far as I know) only defined for Wythoffian uniform polytopes, so I suppose whatever you image by omnitruncated grand antiprism is probably not vertex-transitive (but it probably gives a counterexample for the question for a zonotope with all vertices on a sphere, as already do some $2n$-gons).

Comment: Having said that, I probably found a proof that all vertex-transitive zonotopes are $\Gamma$-permutahedra for some finite reflection group $\Gamma$. However, all I could give right now as an answer are some hints, since I have not formulated every detail. Maybe I should do that.

Comment: @M.Winter: An aside about your comment "omnitruncations are only defined for Wythoffian...": the skeleton of the omnitruncation is the same as the flag graph of a polytope (with facets for each face of P) so by taking this as the definition you can define it for any polytope. It's not a priori obvious that this can be realized as a convex polytope, but this is proved in Lemma 3 of [Polytopes with Preassigned Automorphism Groups](http://doi.org/10.1007/s00454-015-9710-1) (Schulte & Williams, 2015).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**

I recently uploaded a [preprint](https://arxiv.org/abs/1912.10469) in which I work out the details that are missing below.
So in fact, vertex-transitive zonotopes are $\Gamma$-permutahedra.

---

I believe to have (at least a roadmap to) a proof of the following:

> **Theorem.** If $P\subset\Bbb R^d$ is a vertex-transitive zonotope, then $P$ is a $\Gamma$-permutahedron. That is, $P$ is the convex hull of the orbit of an appropriately chosen point $\smash{v\in\Bbb R^d}$ under a finite reflection group $\smash{\Gamma\subset\mathrm{GL}(\Bbb R^d)}$.

In other words, $P$ is the omnitruncation of some uniform polytope (when considered with a certain subgroup of its symmetries).

---

I will give some thoughts about my proof, since I have not thought through every detail:

- Every zonotope can be uniquely written as the Minkowski sum of line segments with pair-wise trivial intersection.
- Let's call $r\in\Bbb R$ a root of $P$ if $\mathrm{conv}\{-r,r\}$ is one of these line segments.
- One then shows that the set of roots of $P$ forms a *root system* (without integrality condition).<sup>1</sup>
- One further shows, that the zonotope $P$ has the same symmetries as its set of roots, hence that its symmetry group is a reflection group.

(until here, I think, David had another approach using the normal fan of $P$).

- Let $\tilde \Gamma$ be the symmetry group of $P$. Since $P$ is vertex-transitive, $P$ is the orbit polytope of some point $\smash{v\in\Bbb R^d}$ w.r.t $\smash{\tilde \Gamma}$. As David observed, this group might be too large to call $P$ a $\smash{\tilde\Gamma}$-permutahedron.
- Consider the subgroup $\Gamma\subseteq\tilde\Gamma$ generated by all reflections in $\tilde\Gamma$ that fix no vertex of $P$. Then $\Gamma$ is a reflection group.
- Show that $P$ is the orbit polytope of $v$ under $\Gamma$. Then $\Gamma$ acts vertex-transitively and -regularly on $P$, hence $P$ is a $\Gamma$-permutahedron.

---

**Some notes on <sup>1</sup>**

Let $R$ be the set of roots of $P$. How to show that $R$ is a root system:

- Choose any two (linearly independent) $r,r'\in R$ and consider the 2-dimensional set $R':=\mathrm{span}\{r,r'\}\cap R$.
- Let $P'$ be the zonotope generated by $R'$. This zonotope is a 2-face of $P$, and by using the argument that $\mathrm{Aut}(P)=\mathrm{Aut}(R)$ one can conclude that from the vertex-transitivity of $P$ follows the vertex-transitivity of $P'$. (This part is sketchy right now, and makes some trouble. How to fix this? I think that that the faces of a vertex-transitive polytope do not necessarily have to be vertex transitive! *Update*: yes they are vertex-transitive, see the preprint)
- It follows that $P'$ is a $2n$-gon with possibly alternating edge lengths.
- One convinces oneself that the roots of $P'$ are a root system ($2n$ roots equally spaces by $\pi/n$, maybe of alternating lengths), that is, $R'$ (and hence $R$) contains the reflection of $r'$ on the hyperplane defined by $r$.
- Since $r$ and $r'$ were chosen arbitrarily, this shows that $R$ is a root system.

Comment: It's bullet point 3 that I want more detail on. Why is reflection over $r^{\perp}$ necessarily one of the symmetries of your polytope? If you get this, I believe you have the rest.

Comment: @DavidESpeyer The point that I have not thought through in detail is how to show that $P$ is an orbit polytope of $v$ w.r.t. $\Gamma$. Might be not too hard, but still a gap for me right now.

Comment: I filled in a detailed part for point 3. However, I still had to be vague on the second point there, and some details are missing. Help is appreciated. But this breaks the proof down to the question of how wild the 2-faces of such a zonotope can be.

Comment: I agree that it comes down to $2$-faces. A direction I have been thinking about is that Nathan Reading gives a characterization of permutahedra by their $2$-skeletons: Theorem 10-2.21 in "Finite Coxeter Groups and the Weak Order", which is Chapter 10 of "Lattice Theory: Special Topics and Applications".

Comment: Here is how I would rephrase what he does: First, the edge graph must be $n$-regular and every pair of adjacent edges must be in a unique $2$-face of even size, so assume these things. Choose a vertex and color the $n$-edges incident to it with $1$, $2$, ..., $n$. Propogate this to an edge coloring of the full graph such that every two face is colored $(i,j,i,j,\dots, i,j)$.  If there are two $2$-faces with the same color pair $(i,j)$ and different numbers of edges, it is not a permutahedron. Otherwise, let $2 m_{ij}$ be the number of edges of an $(i,j)$-colored $2$-face. (continued)

Comment: Then this is the $2$-skeleton of the $W$-permutahedron for $W = \langle s_i | s_i^2=1, (s_i s_j)^{m_{ij}}=1 \rangle$. Moreover, any $n$-dimensional polyhedron which has this as the $2$-skeleton is combinatorially isomorphic to said permutahedron. (That's a bit stronger than what Nathan writes, but I think its right.)

Comment: It's too strong to say $P$ is the omnitruncation of some uniform polytope—for instance, the 3-cube is a vertex-transitive zonotope, and it is the convex hull of the orbit of a point $v$ under a finite reflection group (dihedral symmetry of order 8) with no mirrors through $v$, but it is not the omnitruncation of any polyhedron.

Comment: The cube $well$ is the omnitruncate of the group $A_1\times A_1\times A_1$ (i.e. having for Coxeter-Dynkin diagram 3 separated ringed nodes). - For in the parlance of Coxeter-Dynkin diagrams the omnitruncation is just that graph, which has all nodes ringed.