# Hyperplane arrangements whose regions all have the same shape

Tags: co.combinatorics, mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry, hyperplane-arrangements

Suppose I have a (finite, real, central, essential) hyperplane arrangement $\mathcal{H}$ such that all regions "have the same shape": for any two regions $R,R'$, there is an orthogonal transformation taking $R$ to $R'$ (these transformations are not required to do anything nice to the rest of the arrangement).  Is $\mathcal{H}$ necessarily a reflection arrangement?

Comment: This is more restricted than what you ask, but in [this preprint](https://arxiv.org/abs/1912.10469) I prove that if the arrangement is transitive on the regions, then it is a reflection arrangement (though it is proven via a dual formulation with zonotopes, see also [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/342367/classification-of-vertex-transitive-zonotopes)). You probably know that an arrangement with congruent (aka. same-shaped) regions must be simplicial. As far as I know, no classification of simplicial arrangements exists beyond 3D (and I am not sure whether 3D is settled).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a known open problem (for isometric regions), which, as far as I know, is still not settled.

The dimension 3 case was proved affirmatively in https://arxiv.org/abs/1501.05991, where also some history of the question is outlined. I am not aware of any progress since.